# Removing space from grid when stackpanel is collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I have an app where I display rows of stack panels in a grid. The user can hide rows of stackpanels to "clean up" the grid, and only view/edit what they would like, the idea is to collapse the stackpanels between seperators and the space between closes up.

When I set the stackpanel to Visibility.Collapsed, the stackpanel disappears but the space they occupied is still present.

How do I make the gap go away? (I added the updatelayout, but this doesn't appear to do anything)

What it looks like before:[Before](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14006061/b4.JPG)

What it looks like after:[After](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14006061/After.JPG)

My XAML:

```
    <ScrollViewer Name="scroll" PanningMode="Both" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">50</sys:Double>
            <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}">50</sys:Double>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="RecipeEditorCtrl" VerticalAlignment="Top">                
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

My C#:

```
        ...
        int rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(CNtmp);

        rowIndex++;
        tmpCN = (CollectionNode)RecipeEditorCtrl.Children[rowIndex];
        while (tmpCN.dataType.Text != "SEPERATOR")
        {
            tmpCN.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            rowIndex++;
            tmpCN = (CollectionNode)RecipeEditorCtrl.Children[rowIndex];
        }
        RecipeEditorCtrl.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Expander`? It has this collapsing logic built in.

Comment: Need More code to analyze your issue

Comment: Generally speaking, this means you're using the wrong method laying out items.

Comment: This was a pretty simple example of how were using it, The expander won't work because this will be multiple state (more than expand collapse) as well as the header will normally contain more than just a label. Any additional code I have only pertains to loading the info, this is all I have that does the work. I figured I was probably laying things out incorrectly, What is the correct layout to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can use `RowsDefinitions` and Make each `RowDefinition` `Height` Property to `Auto` then add your `StackPanel` to those rows